ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : instability under high load when working with streamed uploads
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API where I'm uploading files per stream with a POST command. This means, I'm reading the Request.Body (a stream) internally.
As I'm sending it over to 3 other service, the approach is the following:

we have one thread reading the input stream - it reads always chunks of data (e.g. 80k bytes) and places it into 3 queues
we have 3 instances of an self implemented stream which takes these queues to answer the Read(...) method.
the request from the first service to the others are done normally via HttpClient and setting the stream (our self written stream that accesses then the queue with already read chunks)

If our self written stream is in the Read(...) and there is no queued chunks available, then it waits with a Monitor.Wait(...) until the next chunk from the input stream thread comes in. So, it could be that it takes a while to answer the Read(...) call but that shouldn't be a problem, isn't it?
When I'm doing that with 3 or 5 requests in parallel, everything is fine. But when it is under high load with e.g. 50 requests in parallel processed at the same time, I'm getting problems like the stream cannot be read anymore and similar problems.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)   > at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder1.StateMachineBox1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder1.StateMachineBox1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)      at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
at


Edit: this message can be seen on the service where its sent over.
The services are running as docker container in OpenShift. The CPU load is not too high - with 50 requests in parallel 2-3 CPUs, the limit is 16.
I'm wondering what could be the issue here. Each request is handled in an own thread, internally nothing should influence each other. For sure, with 50 stream readings and 150 stream sending in parallel the load is high, but I expected it then just to be slower but not failing at all.
My expectation is that each request has these 4 threads in use. 1 is reading the input stream, 3 are sending it over to further services.
Thanks a lot for help!

I hope you use async for that - async network communication scales much better.  Apart from that - it smells like problem surfacing when there's enough memory pressure. The problem with this description that is immediately noticeable is that you're effectively loading every file in RAM 3 times for every operation and that easily adds up. 2 MB file results in minimal allocation of 6 MB with 50 concurrent requests we're talking 300 MB/average request time. Wouldn't it be simpler to receive data in chunks and send them immediately as they come without all the memory backed streams?

Yes, I'm using async.
Why do you smell a memory pressure issue here? I would simply get OutOfMemoryExceptions which is not the case.
The concept I described is exactly to not have the full file in memory. I'm reading the file in chunks and these chunks are sent over to the other services. As soon they sent, they can be freed by the GC.

In OpenShift I clearly see that I have enough memory left - even when uploading many GBs files I only have 200-300 MB memory in use - so the concept in general is working.
The issue comes somewhere under high load which I don't understand why some streams are getting unstable then.

When this issue happens on load (no source here) it's probably not awaiting something that you should await or a missing a using statement somewhere. Both of these issues surfaces on load, because the GC kicks in much more often and they show up. From the error you posted I expect you are closing the file too soon and somewhere down the pipe something gets unexpected EOS (f.e. the HttpClient reads incomplete file stream). Btw for operation like these I find it much more convenient to use Body(Reader/Writer) from HttpContext, assuming you're in the ASP.NET ecosystem.
